# Mysql - Best primary key for appointments table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm not very expert in SQL and I need to ask an advice about what's the best way to set up a table that will contains appointments.
My doubt is on the primary key.

My ideas are:

1-Use an auto-increment column for the Id of the appointment (for example unsigned integer).
My doubts about this solution are: the index can reachs the overflow even if it's very high and when the number of record grows up performances can decrease?

2-Create a table for every year.
Dubts: it will be complex to mantain and execute queries.

3-Use a composite index.
Dubts: how set it

4-Other?

Thanks.

Comment: How many appointments do you have?  A 4-byte integer is sufficient for most purposes.

Comment: The worse case that I expect is 500 appointments a day, then 182.500 a year.

Comment: . . You'll have nothing to worry about for centuries, even millenia.  Go ahead, use the integer or unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

Use an autoincrement primary key. MySQL will not be able to process a growing table way before your integer will overflow.

MySQL's performance will go down on a large even if you did not have a primary key. This is when you will start thinking about partitioning (your option 2) and archiving old data. But from the beginning autoincrement primary key on a single table should do just fine.

Comment: I've seen billion-row tables that MySQL is happy with.  The lack of a PK is not what will cause performance to decline.  His Option 2 is not using the `PARTITION` feature.  An AI PK will not be "just fine" if he needs to search by anything other than the PK, such as a date range.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Do you think you will exceed 4 billion rows?  Performance degrades *if* you don't have suitable indexes for your queries, *not* because of table size.  (Well, there is a slight degradation, but not worth worrying about.)  Based on 182K/year, `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (16M max) will suffice.

2 - NO!  This is a common question; the answer is always "do not create identical tables".

3 - What column or combination of columns are UNIQUE for the table?  Simply list them inside `PRIMARY KEY (...)`

Number 3 is usually preferred.  If there is no unique column(s), go with Number 1.

182K rows per year does not justify `PARTITIONing`.  Consider it if you expect more than a million rows.  (Here's an easy prediction: You *will* re-design this schema before 182K grows to a million.)